# What does the following assembly does for the following .c file

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-construction, sparc

I have written the following code, can you explain me what does the assembly tell here.

```
typedef struct
{
    int abcd[5];
} hh;

void main()
{
    printf("%d", ((hh*)0)+1);
}
```

Assembly:

```
        .file   "aa.c"
        .section        ".rodata"
        .align 8
.LLC0:

        .asciz  "%d\n"
        .section        ".text"
        .align 4
        .global main
        .type   main, #function
        .proc   020
main:

        save    %sp, -112, %sp
        sethi   %hi(.LLC0), %g1
        or      %g1, %lo(.LLC0), %o0
        mov     20, %o1
        call    printf, 0
         nop
        return  %i7+8
         nop
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.2.1"
```

Comment: SPARC. The `save` instruction and the registers named `%gN`, `%oN` and `%iN` are a dead giveaway.

Comment: Since you're using `gcc`, you might want to try compiling with the flags `-g -Wa,-aldh` which will print a listing that interleaves the high-level source code with the generated assembly.

Comment: And/or `-fverbose-asm` to comment each line with the high-level var names of the operands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oh wow, SPARC assembly language, I haven't seen that in *years*.

I guess we go line by line?  I'm going to skip some of the uninteresting boilerplate.

```
        .section        ".rodata"
        .align 8
.LLC0:
        .asciz  "%d\n"
```

This is the string constant you used in `printf` (so obvious, I know!) The important things to notice are that it's in the `.rodata` section (sections are divisions of the eventual executable image; this one is for "read-only data" and will in fact be immutable at runtime) and that it's been given the *label* `.LLC0`.  Labels that begin with a dot are private to the object file.  Later, the compiler will refer to that label when it wants to load the address of the string constant.

```
        .section        ".text"
        .align 4
        .global main
        .type   main, #function
        .proc   020
main:
```

`.text` is the section for actual machine code.  This is the boilerplate header for defining the global function named `main`, which at the assembly level is no different from any other function (in C -- not necessarily so in C++).  I don't remember what `.proc 020` does.

```
        save    %sp, -112, %sp
```

Save the previous register window and adjust the stack pointer downward.  If you don't know what a register window is, you need to read the architecture manual: http://sparc.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/v8.pdf.gz.  (V8 is the last 32-bit iteration of SPARC, V9 is the first 64-bit one.  This appears to be 32-bit code.)

```
        sethi   %hi(.LLC0), %g1
        or      %g1, %lo(.LLC0), %o0
```

This two-instruction sequence has the net effect of loading the address `.LLC0` (that's your string constant) into register `%o0`, which is the first *outgoing* argument register.  (The arguments *to* this function are in the *incoming* argument registers.)

```
        mov     20, %o1
```

Load the immediate constant 100 into `%o1`, the second outgoing argument register.  This is the value computed by `((foo *)0)+1`. It's 20 because your `struct foo` is 20 bytes long (five 4-byte `int`s) and you asked for the second one within the array starting at address zero.

Incidentally, computing an offset from a pointer is only well-defined in C when there is actually a sufficiently large array at the address of the base pointer; `((foo *)0)` is a null pointer, so there isn't an array there, so the expression `((foo *)0)+1` technically has undefined behavior.  GCC 4.2.1, targeting hosted SPARC, happens to have interpreted it as "pretend there is an arbitrarily large array of `foo`s at address zero and compute the expected offset for array member 1", but other (especially newer) compilers may do something completely different.

```
        call    printf, 0
        nop
```

Call `printf`.  I don't remember what the zero is for.  The `call` instruction has a delay slot (again, read the architecture manual) which is filled in with a do-nothing instruction, `nop`.

```
        return  %i7+8
        nop
```

Jump to the address in register `%i7` plus eight.  This has the effect of returning from the current function.

`return` also has a delay slot, which is filled in with another `nop`.  There is supposed to be a `restore` instruction in this delay slot, matching the `save` at the top of the function, so that `main`'s caller gets its register window back.  I don't know why it's not there.  Discussion in the comments talks about `main` possibly not needing to pop the register window, and/or your having declared `main` as `void main()` (which is not guaranteed to work with any C implementation, unless its documentation specifically says so, and is *always* bad style) ... but pushing and not popping the register window is such a troublesome thing to do on a SPARC that I don't find either explanation convincing.  I might even call it a compiler bug.

Comment: @Zack: `main()` is special in that its caller doesn't have any expectations on preserved state - that includes the register window. `main()`'s caller will always only exit afterwards (just `dis` the resulting executable and look for `__start`) Hence, no `restore` required in this specific case. There's probably a mention of this in the SPARC ABI somewhere ...

Comment: @FrankH. Usually the last line of `_start` is `exit(main(argc, argv, environ))` or the equivalent in assembly.  Doesn't it need to pop the register window in order for the argument to `exit` to wind up in the right place?  (This may be a silly question, it has been a very long time since I touched a SPARC box.)

Comment: @Zack: Notice the erroneous declaration `void main()` - does that answer the question ?

Answer (score 1):

The assembly calls `printf`, passing your text buffer and the number 20 on the stack (which is what you asked for in a roundabout way).

Comment: I get 20 from this: `mov     20, %o1`

Comment: ... yeah, that's not what it used to say.  Sorry for the noise.  +1 for the much shorter answer :)